# Editing help panels hidden

Tags: support, bug, user-interface

On my laptop I only have a 1366x768 screen, as a result when I go to edit one of my answers there is the *How to Format* panel on the right and some other panel (*How to Edit*?) that I can't see and I can't scroll it into view.

Now I'm aware of the problem with it [overflowing onto the footer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel) and that doesn't bother me, as it allows it remain visible. Unfortunately from the below screenshots, the top is not always visible and can't be read (note that it remains no matter how far I scroll down the page):

[image]